# How to check the readiness probes on Services Bus?

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, readinessprobe

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application running on a docker container in kubernetes. It consists of two services which send data from the one to the other via Azure Service Bus.
Hot to check on the Service Bus a readiness probe?
I Was trying to find an API on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus?view=azure-dotnet and I did not found any fitting function.
Do you use it? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

There are [some endpoints](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Controllers/HostController.cs) that can be used but are protected behind system/admin keys. But it seems that there is [an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5259) already filed to expose endpoints for Kubernetes You can follow the thread for updates or you can also follow up on this thread.

Comment: Could you provide an example how to use these endpoints?

Comment: @canvee you may follow https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/ but I have mentioned that there are some issues with that. Please check : https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5259